# Cursor Exception after deleting a row in my android app

Tags: android

Do not know where I am getting this wrong. After deleting a row when I click  on  my list view, the app exits. Below is my source code:

```
 private void showlist() {

    ArrayList<ContactListItems> contactList = new ArrayList<ContactListItems>();
    contactList.clear();
    mydb = new DBHelper(this);
    String query = "SELECT * FROM DBbooking ";
    Cursor c1 = mydb.selectQuery(query);
    if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0) {
        if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ContactListItems contactListItems = new ContactListItems();

                contactListItems.setSlno(c1.getString(c1
                        .getColumnIndex("id")));
                contactListItems.setName(c1.getString(c1
                        .getColumnIndex("Firstname")));
                contactListItems.setPhone(c1.getString(c1
                        .getColumnIndex("Lastname")));
                contactList.add(contactListItems);

            } while (c1.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    c1.close();

    ContactListAdapter contactListAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(
            Bookings.this, contactList);
    lvCustomList.setAdapter(contactListAdapter);

   lvCustomList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //  int id_To_Search = arg2;

            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putInt("id", arg2);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Details.class);

            intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Part of the code that views the clicked item
    public void dislplaybookings() {

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();


    int passedvaluefromformeractivity = extras.getInt("id");
    int realvalue = passedvaluefromformeractivity+1 ;
    mydb = new DBHelper(this);


 Cursor rs = mydb.getData(realvalue);

rs.moveToFirst();
String trn = rs.getString(1);
Firstname.setText((CharSequence) trn);
Firstname.setFocusable(false);
Firstname.setClickable(false);
```

myDBHelpe for selection

```
public Cursor getData(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from DBbooking where id="+id+"", null );
    return res;
}
```

Delete called

```
public void deletdata(){ 
   mydb = new DBHelper(this); 
   String trnid= "" + Trans_ID.getText(); 
   mydb.deleteTitle(trnid); 
   Toast.makeText(Details.this, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Bookings.class); 
   startActivity(intent); 
}
```

Delete

```
public boolean deleteTitle(String TransID) { 
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
   return db.delete(DBbooking_TABLE_NAME, DBbooking_COLUMN_TRANS_ID + "=" + TransID, null) > 0; 
}
```

my logcat.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0       requested, with a size     of 0
```

Please I need help to make my app not exiting after deleting any row

Comment: There should be more error lines in your logcat starting with `E/something: SomeError`
Please edit them into the main post.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, check if the `rs` cursor returned anything just like you did in `showlist()`

```
Cursor rs = mydb.getData(realvalue);

if (rs != null && rs.getCount() != 0){
  rs.moveToFirst();
  String trn = rs.getString(1);
  Firstname.setText((CharSequence) trn);
  Firstname.setFocusable(false);
  Firstname.setClickable(false);
}
```

Also, where are you actually performing the delete?

Comment: I have just added the code block above and still have the below error.        Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{gstuntz.splashscreen/gstuntz.splashscreen.Details}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0

Comment: That was just to make sure you have a valid cursor before doing anything with it. Can you post the code where you perform the delete?

Comment: public void deletdata(){

    mydb = new DBHelper(this);
  

    String trnid=  "" + Trans_ID.getText();
    mydb.deleteTitle(trnid);
    Toast.makeText(Details.this, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Bookings.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

Comment: and below is the deleteTittle();

Comment: Can you add it to the original post so it's more readable? And the LogCat should have an `at SomePackage SomeLine` underneath the error you posted.

Comment: public boolean deleteTitle(String TransID)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(DBbooking_TABLE_NAME, DBbooking_COLUMN_TRANS_ID + "=" + TransID, null) > 0;
    }

Comment: Basically what I want to achieve now is to set the details from my clicked list using a row called TransID in database. So I want to use the column data as a perquisite for setting details from my next activity. All I get from the list view with my current code is integer that starts with 0 as the fist Item on click. I want to be using actual value from my list.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you sammy T..I have been able to resolve the issue by using a costume adapter.
Below.

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

           String tx2 = ((TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.tv_slno)).getText().toString();


            Intent i = new Intent(Bookings.this, Details.class);
            i.putExtra("t2", tx2);
            startActivity(i);

        }
```

Comment: Where tv_slno is the ID of the textview created with my custom adapter.

Comment: That's great. Don't forget to mark your answer as resolved later.